# How can I attach the RubyMine debugger to a docker container inside a Vagrant box?

Tags: docker, debugging, vagrant, jetbrains-ide, rubymine

I'm working on a Rails app where our development environment is set up to run in a docker container inside of a Vagrant box. When configuring a Vagrant remote interpreter in RubyMine, I'm asked for the path to ruby executable. The problem is that the ruby executable is inside the running Rails docker container, so you can't provide a path to it. Any thoughts about how to make this work? Is it possible?

I tried finding an executable in the Vagrant box, but it doesn't exists because Ruby lives in the docker container.

Comment: If it's not possible to configure the SDK as the docker one, then you can try connecting to it via SSH (but the container should stay running)

Comment: Thanks for your input, Olivia. I'm wondering if you can clarify this a little bit. Does the running Rails Docker container inside the Vagrant box have a unique ssh address that I can access directly from my local machine in Rubymine? I'm not sure quite what you mean when you say that the "container should stay running". The container is always running in the Vagrant box, since the box is created for the explicit purpose of creating and running the container. My issue is that I cannot provide Rubymine with a path to a Ruby project executable.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with that type of setup, because usually Vagrant is used separately from the Docker and both of them are supported in RubyMine (if used not one from another). But if it's possible to reach the Docker container via SSH, then it'd be possible to configure remote SDK that way.